# Calculate difference between entry in csv column using PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I have csv file with data (example bellow):

```
+----------+----------+-------------------------------+
|   Name   |  Status  |             Time              |
+----------+----------+-------------------------------+
| Service1 | Running  | "2019/10/20 07:49:40,836 GMT" |
| Service1 | Shutdown | "2019/10/15 20:07:45,021 GMT" |
| Service1 | Running  | "2019/10/10 20:07:45,021 GMT" |
+----------+----------+-------------------------------+
```

With this value, I have to calculate how long the given name was in running state in past 30 days.
It is not issue calculate with one entry in file but a given name can have any number of occurrences in the column name.
The above example is just simple example, name Service1 2019/10/10 was in running but 2019/10/15 was in shutdown so beetwen this two times was not active.
Next active time occurs 2019/10/20 and from this time till the current date was active.
Now I would like to calculate how long in past 30 days Service1 was in active state (Running).
Could you point to which method should be use to calculate this difference?

Comment: Use `Import-Csv` to get the data as object. Get all Services inside the file with `Select-Object -Property Name -Unique` and use `foreach` loop with `Where-Object` to get the needed rows for each service.

Comment: This problem is called "gaps and islands".

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
$records = Import-CSV -Path 'D:\service.csv' -Delimiter (Get-Culture).TextInfo.ListSeparator | select -Property @{n='Time';e={[datetime]::parseexact($_.Time.Replace('"',''),"yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss,fff GMT",$null)}},* -Exclude 'Time' | Sort-Object -Property Name, Time

$completeTimeSpan = 30 * 24 * 60 * 60
$currentDateTime  = Get-Date

for( $i = 0; $i -lt $records.Count; $i++ ) {

    $serviceName   = $records[$i].Name
    $opStatus      = 3  # 0 = down, 1 = up, 3 = start
    $upTime        = 0
    $downTime      = 0
    $dateLastEvent = $null

    while( $i -lt $records.Count -and $serviceName -eq $records[$i].Name ) {

        $ts = New-TimeSpan -Start $records[$i].Time -End $currentDateTime

        if( $ts.Days -le 30 ) {

            if( $opStatus -eq 1 ) {
                $ts        = New-TimeSpan -Start $dateLastEvent -End $records[$i].Time
                $uptime   += $ts.TotalSeconds
                if( $records[$i].Status -eq 'Shutdown' ) {
                    $opStatus = 0
                }
            }
            elseif( $opStatus -eq 0 )  {
                $ts        = New-TimeSpan -Start $dateLastEvent -End $records[$i].Time
                $downtime += $ts.TotalSeconds
                if( $records[$i].Status -eq 'Running' ) {
                    $opStatus = 1
                }
            }
            elseif( $opStatus -eq 3 ) {
                if( $records[$i].Status -eq 'Shutdown' ) {
                    $opStatus = 0
                }
                else {
                    $opStatus = 1
                }
                $dateLastEvent = $records[$i].Time
            }
        }

        $i++
        if( $i -eq $records.Count -or $serviceName -ne $records[$i].Name ) {
            "Service: $servicename Uptime: $upTime $(($uptime / $completeTimeSpan))% DownTime: $downTime $(($downtime / $completeTimeSpan))%"
            if( $i -lt $records.Count ) {
                $serviceName = $records[$i].Name
            }
        }
    }
    $i--

}
```

Comment: thank you. this is a nice piece of code, but it looks that it calculates everything base on the first oldest value, any everything example service1 and service2, service3 use same date for calculation.